# How can I test the BlueKeep exploit?

Tags: exploit, virtualbox

I want to do the BlueKeep exploit, but I want to do it legally. I know how to do the exploit, I am just trying to figure out how to set up something that is vulnerable to BlueKeep. How can I accomplish this? The only thing I can think of that might work is setting up a VM, but I am not sure how I could make a VM that is vulnerable to BlueKeep. All I can find online is that it needs to be some sort of Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2, but I am not sure how to configure it so that it is actually vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This is only intended to be used in an isolated lab environment.

As you pointed out you need a version of Windows 7 SP1 or Windows Server 2008 R2.  If you have one of these OS versions, you'll probably need to remove patches from the system.

> If you've got a Windows 7 or Windows Vista machine, click the Start button and choose Programs-->Programs and Features-->View installed updates. You'll see a list of your most recent updates. Click the one you want to remove, click Uninstall, then follow the prompts. That should do the trick.

The other thing I've seen several write-ups state is that you need to set `fdisablecam = 0`.  In `regedit` track down `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\Winstations\RDP-Tcp\fDisableCam` and set it to 0.

Note: One write-up (listed in references) turns off the Windows Firewall.  I'm not clear that is necessary but if you're not able to exploit your host give that a try.

**References**
[Metasploit BlueKeep Doc](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/04e8752b9b74cbaad7cb0ea6129c90e3172580a2/documentation/modules/exploit/windows/rdp/cve_2019_0708_bluekeep_rce.md)
[Exploiting BlueKeep](https://medium.com/@jonathanchelmus/bluekeepn-it-real-9e99a45dfceb)
[How to uninstall any Windows Update](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2867079/how-how-to-uninstall-any-windows-update.html)